# Is there a cleaner way to stop React rendering on initial load?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So my react class calls to a json response and then renders.

But as it stands, the class will render on initial load then render again when response has come back.

To get around this I have do this -

```
componentDidMount: function() {

        axios.get.......
          .then(res => {
            const jobs = res.data;
            this.setState({ jobs });
          });
  },

render: function () {
      if (Object.keys(this.state.jobs).length == 0)
      {

      }
      else {
          return (
              <div>
                  {this.state.jobs.data.map(function (ob) {
                      return <li key={ob.id}>{ob.name}</li>

                  })}

              </div>
          )
      }
      return null;
  }

});
```

Is there a nicer way to do this? without using an if statement?

Comment: I would return the null inside your if statement. I don't think there's an issue with using an if inside your render. The initial render won't do anything, and when you get your data, it will compare the html and apply changes.

Comment: `if(!this.state.jobs) return null;
return (<your-html />);` would be a little shorter, but there's nothing wrong with it running the initial time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React always has to render in the initial load. So you just need to render null like you already did. Code wise, maybe you can write

```
return this.state.jobs.data ? <YourTemplate /> : null;
```

which is cleaner.

Comment: Perfect for a pure component, or a function